# CGSUpdateManager Warning after presenting a view controller

Tags: swift, warnings, backtrace, presentviewcontroller

I'm receiving a CGSUpdateManager Warning which happens roughly 10 seconds after I've presented my view controller from a NSOpenPanel completion handler when the user presses "Import".
The code where I'm triggering my view controller looks like this.

```
func ImportCSV() {
        // Setup Panel
        let fileType: [String] = ["csv", "CSV"]
        var importPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        importPanel.title = "Import"
        importPanel.prompt = "Import"
        importPanel.allowedFileTypes = fileType
        importPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        importPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        importPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        importPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        // Begin Panel
        importPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in
            if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
                self.importFileWithURL(importPanel.URL!)
            }
        }

        }

    func importFileWithURL(URL: NSURL){
                    let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)! as NSStoryboard
                    let importFileView = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("test") as ImportFileViewController
                    self.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(importFileView)
                    importFileView.fileToImport(URL)
    }
```

The Warning I'm receiving is:

```
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x21cab token 0x8bfffffffff985e
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: Backtrace (at 21180.2):
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  0   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8c452095 CGSBacktraceCreate + 59
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  1   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8c4714f8 _ZN16CGSUpdateManager14disable_updateEv + 84
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  2   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a4b8b6b -[NSSavePanel ok:] + 300
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  3   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff8d4d9cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a0d2b71 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 452
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a0d2970 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2a886c __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  7   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff8d4d9cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a11b509 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  9   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff8d4d9cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a136085 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2775
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a1352b9 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 491
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a134899 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 714
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a632a18 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 12721
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a0b916e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 446
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a06b451 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4183
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  16  AppKit                              0x00007fff89ef7608 -[NSApplication run] + 711
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  17  AppKit                              0x00007fff89ee2a14 NSApplicationMain + 1832
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  18  Stamp                               0x000000010004f152 top_level_code + 34
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  19  Stamp                               0x000000010004f18a main + 42
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff90c895c9 start + 1
Mar  8 19:39:05 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local Stamp[6044] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  21  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
```

What does this warning mean and should I be worried about it?